# Private IP remains same every time but public IP changes every time we restart EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Why is that private IP of an EC2 instance remains same even after we stop it whereas the public IP of the instance changes every time it is stopped and restarted?

Comment: And why is this a problem?

Answer (score 3):

There is a pool of public IP addresses which are assigned to an EC2 instance every time you start (or restart) the instance.

The IP addresses are reused and returned to the pool once the instance is stopped (this helps to use the addresses efficiently).

Take from the Amazon docs:

> A public IP address is assigned to your instance from Amazon's pool of
>   public IP addresses, and is not associated with your AWS account. When
>   a public IP address is disassociated from your instance, it is
>   released back into the public IP address pool, and you cannot reuse
>   it.

It makes sense to keep the private IP address same because it may be used for the communication between the instances (which are in the same subnet).

There might be a solution enabling you to keep the same public address:

> If you require a persistent public IP address that can be associated
>   to and from instances as you require, use an Elastic IP address
>   instead. You can allocate your own Elastic IP address, and associate
>   it with your instance. For more information, see Elastic IP Addresses
>   (EIP).

Take a look [HERE](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html).